com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException when trying to read a json file
I am trying to write an endpoint to return all the data in a seperate JSON file.
This is my code for now.
UserController.java
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<User> getAllUsers() throws IOException {
        return userService.findAll();
    }
    
}

UserService.java
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class UserService {
    
    private static final String FILE_PATH = "C:\\Users\\test\\Users.json"; 
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private List<User> getUsers() throws IOException {
        File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
        if (file.exists()) {
            return objectMapper.readValue(file, objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, User.class));
        }
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public List<User> findAll() throws IOException {
        return getUsers();
    }

}

Json file
[
{"user_id": 9, 
"username": "user9", 
"password": xxxx, 
"name": "abcd", 
"college": "test", 
"is_edited": false, 
"is_deleted": false, 
"user_type_id": 1
},
{
"user_id": 10, 
"username": "user10", 
"password": xxxx, 
"name": "abcd", 
"college": "test", 
"is_edited": false, 
"is_deleted": false, 
"user_type_id": 2
}
]

When I try to invoke the endpoint with postman, below is the exception I am getting.
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.util.ArrayList<com.example.demo.User>` from Object value (token `JsonToken.START_OBJECT`)
 at [Source: REDACTED (`StreamReadFeature.INCLUDE_SOURCE_IN_LOCATION` disabled); line: 1, column: 1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1767) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1541) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1488) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.CollectionDeserializer.handleNonArray(CollectionDeserializer.java:402) ~[jackson-databind-2.17.2.jar:2.17.2]

Can someone please help?

Can you get a single User to start with? Try objectMapper.readValue("{\"user_id\":10,\"username\":\"user10\",...}", User.class) - does that work?

Also, check if there are any strange bytes in your file, e.g. var bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Path.of("C:\\Users\\test\\Users.json")); System.out.printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x%n", bytes[0], bytes[1], bytes[2], bytes[3]);

Is the value of password really something, and not "something"? This seems fishy to me, I believe that's not a valid value. If I remember correctly Jackson needs special  configuration to handle such invalid values.

Hi I think your Json might be invalid. The xxxx in your passwords should be between quotes.
"password": "xxxx",

This error is caused by ObjectMapper expecting a list of User objects, so it expects to receive the beginning of the list as a [ character, but it receives a { character, as if it were reading a single object. It looks like the contents of the file you are reading are different from what you specified in the question.
